# How do delete deb package with dependencies

Tags: linux

I'm trying to delete linux kernel deb package using command sudo dpkg -r linux-header-3.19.8.992 but fails saying dependencies are there

Comment: You can either use    sudo apt-get remove packagename     if you know the name of the package, or if you don't, search for it using                          apt-cache search crazy-app and then remove it using apt get

You can also use dpkg --remove packagename.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get purge <package-name>
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 0):

**sudo apt-get remove packagename**
or 
**sudo dpkg -r package_name**

for more info https://askubuntu.com/questions/22200/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-package